# Error on function php

Tags: php, html

I want go to the home pages as the privilege of user that current logged in.
When i am trying to open the page that having the link it goes to the home page. What changes that i need on my code

```
<body>
    <a href="<?php home(); ?> ">Home</a>
</body

function home()
    {
        if($_SESSION['privillage']=="ADMIN")
        {
            header('location:admin_home.php');
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['privillage']=='SUPERVISOR')
        {
            header('location:home.php');
        }
        else
        {
            header('location:user_home.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you referring to? Can you please include them in your post?

Comment: do you have `@session_start()` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: `<body>` tag is not closed!!! :D

Comment: The `home()` function doesn't echo anything. It makes no sense to put it inside `<a href="">`.

Comment: wow... it seems you didn't understand the meaning of the `header()` function... if you're trying to write an hyperlink, just use `echo` in your `home()` function ...

Comment: You can not link to function that returns header. You should use echo links

Comment: yes session works but i cant access the page where the link used. Its directly go to the home page as privilege when try to open the page.

Comment: echo i tried not working

Comment: may be you have to capitalize the first letter of "location" use "Location" in header('Location:user_home.php'); change all location to Location first letter capital :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header('location` is used if you want a PHP script to redirect the browser to another page. What you are trying to do is simply changing the `href` based on certain conditions.

```
function home()
{
    if($_SESSION['privillage']=="ADMIN")
    {
        return 'admin_home.php';
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['privillage']=='SUPERVISOR')
    {
        return 'home.php';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'user_home.php';
    }
}
```

For readability, you could consider using [PHP's switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 5):

Your function is being used inside an `<a href="...">`, so it's clearly supposed to *`return`* a URL (also you need to `echo` it)

Your current code is trying to redirect the user immediately, which won't work because you've already sent `<a href="`.

Try:

```
function home() {
    if($_SESSION['privillage'] == "ADMIN") return "admin_home.php";
    if($_SESSION['privillage'] == "SUPERVISOR") return "home.php";
    return "user_home.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you have to capitalize the first letter of "location" use "Location" in header('Location:user_home.php'); :)